# DeRham Cohomology of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I've learned that the dimension of $H_{dR}^0(M)$ — the  $0^{\text{th}}$De Rham Cohomology Group of a manifold $M$ — equals the number of connected components of $M$. But if $M = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, then according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#Punctured_Euclidean_space):

$$\dim H_{dR}^0(M)  = 1.$$

But $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ clearly has *two* connected components, so I'm confused as to how this can be possible. Any clarification would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Unless it's using reduced cohomology, the formula in Wikipedia should have the assumption that $n > 1$ in it. The space $S^0$ is not connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The statement in Wikipedia is not correct. They are trying to cover the de Rham cohomology groups $H^k_{\text{dR}}(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})$ for all $k$ and $n$ simultaneously, but overlooked this exceptional case.

Comment: Thanks! I just fixed the error on the wikipedia page.

Comment: @chaad: You've introduced a new error. Note that $H^1_{\text{dR}}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}) = 0$ not $\mathbb{R}^2$. Maybe it would be better if you write $$H^k_{\text{dR}}(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}) \cong \begin{cases} \mathbb{R}^2 & n = 1, k = 0\\ \mathbb{R} & n > 1, k = 0, n - 1\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Comment: Gotcha. I'll fix it up!

Comment: @chaad: It now states $H^1_{\text{dR}}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}) \cong \mathbb{R}$ which is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks - fixed it.